# JNDI lookup of local stateless session bean using Glassfish 2.1 causes exception

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, jndi

Currently we are using Glassfish 2.1 as our application container. We have an application that is using EJB's ( 3.0 ) and JPA. 
The application runs Oracle Coherence, and uses a CacheLoader to load data from the Database. The CacheLoader is a POJO that uses JNDI to find the local instance of the EJB.

Coherence has a feature called ServiceGuardian, which kills any of the Coherence threads that have timedout during an operation.

The JNDI lookup works correctly, but if there is a communication failure and the threads have been killed, the consecutive calls cause the JNDI lookups to fail.
Debugging the code shows that the InitialContext does not have any bindings in "java:comp"

Is there a reason why the JNDI lookup fails after the threads have been killed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!